# Flexbox Items Not Vertically Centering In Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, tailwind-css

I am making a navbar in Tailwind consisting of links but I cannot get them to vertically center:

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

[image]

Steps I have tried:

1. `items-center`
2. `justify-center`

Setting the parent to `flex-col`

None of these options work.

How do you get the links to be exactly in the middle of the navbar vertically ?

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Logo from '../images/Logo.png'

const Navbar = () => {

    return (
        <div className="flex justify-between items-center bg-gray-900">
            <div className="">
            <img className="w-40 py-2 px-2" src={Logo}></img>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center">
                <p className="px-4 text-white">About</p>
                <p className="px-4 text-white">Books</p>
                <p className="px-4 text-white">Videos</p>
                <p className="px-4 text-white">Quotes</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: Your code works fine in isolation ([see here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ceyPK00nO0)). Have you used the inspector in the browser developer tools to check what styles are being applied or perhaps overridden?

Answer (score 0):

The divs inside the flex class are aligned at the center, but the issue appears to be the first dive with the `h-24` class which also contains the logo image. The logo aligns at the top of the div with the height of `h-24` which is taller than the div containing the menu items. If you get rid of the `h-24` or align the image vertically, they all align vertically. Try this:

```
<div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-gray-900">
    <div class="h-24 flex items-center">
      <img class="w-40 py-2 px-2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x50"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="flex">
        <p class="px-4 text-white">About</p>
        <p class="px-4 text-white">Books</p>
        <p class="px-4 text-white">Videos</p>
        <p class="px-4 text-white">Quotes</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this solution doesn't work - looks exactly the same

Comment: @JuliusGoddard look at this link. It seems fine here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/0Kqkw8o6eR

Answer (score 0):

It is working just fine. Please recheck the code you have sent, is it what it is producing the output you have produced in your question.

```
<div class="flex justify-between items-center bg-gray-900 h-24">
    <div class="">
      <img class="w-40 py-2 px-2" src=""></img>
    </div>
    <div class="flex ">
        <p class="px-4 text-white">About</p>
        <p class="px-4 text-white">Books</p>
        <p class="px-4 text-white">Videos</p>
        <p class="px-4 text-white">Quotes</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The output generated by the following code :

[image]

Comment: See the picture I added in the edit to prove that the code above is producing the correct result - Maybe same code - two different results ?

Comment: Specify the height i.e h-24 and try and produce the logo image in the question. I will try to help you out

Comment: The height of the logo makes no difference - when I make it smaller - the navbar stays the same height and the menu in the same place.

Comment: Could you possibly send me the github link of the file, i'll debug the answer for you . Because as far i see, the bug doesn't exist here, it exits prior to calling the navbar. Navbar has a constant height i think

Comment: I have come up with a workaround - please view answer

Comment: where is the workaround it ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The problem is that the list items were in

tags and not  tags - when changing the links from

to , the list items centered vertically automatically without any further changes needed.

```
import React from 'react'
import Logo from '../images/Logo.png'

const Navbar = () => {

    return (
        <div className="flex justify-between items-center bg-gray-900 fixed inset-x-0 z-40">
            <div className="">
            <img className="w-40 px-2 mt-6" src={Logo}></img>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center mt-6">
                <p className="px-4 text-white">About</p>
                <p className="px-4 text-white">Books</p>
                <p className="px-4 text-white">Videos</p>
                <p className="px-4 text-white">Quotes</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

[image]

Comment: This is not the actual answer. Navbar for some reason has bottom padding of pb-6

Comment: How can it not be the answer if it looks right ?

Comment: Because you are not finding the error, instead embedding hard coded value which seems to be momentarily correct.

Comment: But it works at all screen sizes so who cares if they are hardcoded?

Comment: The one who wants to know the root cause of the error cares :)

Comment: Fair enough - but by the sounds of it - if it looks normal on for you - maybe it's just screwing around on my machine for some reason ? - The project isn't on Github yet so Im afraid I can't show you.

Comment: New update Mr Acharya if you are still interested... when I changed the links from <p> to <a> they corrected themselves - any idea why ?

Comment: Finally makes sense! This was the trouble maker. Because <p> is a block element meaning it streches accros the screen, <a> is the span element meaning it takes the minimal width. Because of which there were orientation issues